# Vanilla JavaScript equivalent to appendTo() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I am struggling to find a solution to my current issue where I want to create a JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's .appendTo(). I can only see solutions where it's telling me to create a new div in vanilla JavaScript but my aim is to move an already existing div into another existing div.

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="container"></div>

jQuery(".button").appendTo(".container");
```

This works how I expect it to in the console but I'm hoping for a vanilla JavaScript equivalent to this solution if possible? Please can anyone help?

Comment: Would this not suffice?: document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0]);

Comment: @MattKae that answered my question thank-you so much!

Comment: Here's another way: https://jsfiddle.net/qen1h8cg/